# How to remove trailing comma from a object inside a json array using dataweave?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How to remove trailing commas from each line of the object inside the json array?
sample input:

```
[
  {
    "dc": "cn=Cggzci,dc=maxcrc,dc=com",
    "objectClass": "top",
    "objectClass": "person",
    "cn": "Cggzci",
    "sn": "Mqemdv"
  },
  {
    "dc": "cn=Vntlww,dc=maxcrc,dc=com",
    "objectClass": "top",
    "objectClass": "person",
    "cn": "Vntlww",
    "sn": "Fehiqr"
  }
]
```

Dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var test = (write(payload,'application/json'))
---
test replace /\[\n|\n\]|\{|\},\n|\}|"/ with ""
```

Output received:

```
dc: cn=Cggzci,dc=maxcrc,dc=com,
objectClass: top,
objectClass: person,
cn: Cggzci,
sn: Mqemdv

dc: cn=Vntlww,dc=maxcrc,dc=com,
objectClass: top,
objectClass: person,
cn: Vntlww,
sn: Fehiqr
```

Require output should be without trailing commas in each line and remove spaces beginning each line.

Comment: %dw 2.0
output text/plain
var test = (write(payload,'application/json'))
---
test replace /\[\n|\n\]|\{|\},\n|\}|"/ with ""

Comment: please paste the expected output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to avoid regular expressions for things like this. It is simpler to transform the structure of the data.

This solution assumes that the structure is a list of objects. It makes no assumptions on the structure of each object.

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
fun printRecord(x)=x pluck ($$ as String ++ ": " ++ $) joinBy "\n"
---
payload map printRecord($) joinBy "\n\n"
```

Output:

```json
dc: cn=Cggzci,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
cn: Cggzci
sn: Mqemdv

dc: cn=Vntlww,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
cn: Vntlww
sn: Fehiqr
```

Comment: Loved your solution

Comment: I didn't realize you posted another but they are basically the same, though yours has better usage of types.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to implement your ask is not by doing replace but by handling the data structure and generating your output

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain

fun toFlat(value: Array<Object>): String =
    value map ((item, index) -> toFlat(item))
        joinBy  "\n\n"

fun toFlat(value: Object) : String = 
    value pluck ((value, key, index) -> "$(key): $(value as String)") 
          joinBy  "\n"   
---
toFlat(payload)
```

This will output what you want and doesn't depend on your input values but rather on your input shape an Array of Objects